# Cisco 2811 missing serial interfaces

Tags: cisco

I'm trying to bring up PPP over a T1 port on a Cisco 2811.  I recently upgraded the firmware to 12.4(24)T2:

```
cisco-2811#show ver
Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
```

It has 4 slots installed with T1/E1 ports (three 2-port modules and one 1-port module):

```
cisco-2811#show diag
Slot 0:
    C2811 Motherboard with 2FE and integrated VPN Port adapter, 2 ports
    ...

    WIC Slot 0:
    VWIC2-1MFT-T1/E1 - 1-Port RJ-48 Multiflex Trunk - T1/E1
    ...

    WIC Slot 1:
    VWIC2-2MFT-T1/E1 - 2-Port RJ-48 Multiflex Trunk - T1/E1
    ...

    WIC Slot 2:
    VWIC2-2MFT-T1/E1 - 2-Port RJ-48 Multiflex Trunk - T1/E1
    ...

    WIC Slot 3:
    VWIC2-2MFT-T1/E1 - 2-Port RJ-48 Multiflex Trunk - T1/E1
    ...
```

I have specified the card types as T1 and rebooted.  I can see the Controller interfaces in the `show run` output, but I still don't have any `Serial` interfaces in the `show run` or in the `interface ?` output.  I've pasted my full configuration below.  Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks,
Nathan Alderson

```
cisco-2811#show run
Building configuration...


Current configuration : 1433 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname cisco-2811
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
card type t1 0 0
card type t1 0 1
card type t1 0 2
card type t1 0 3
logging message-counter syslog
enable secret 5 $1$4REP$JN8wnnSMwWfdkWv6PDVbf/
enable password PASSWORD
!
no aaa new-model
no network-clock-participate wic 0
no network-clock-participate wic 1
no network-clock-participate wic 2
no network-clock-participate wic 3
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
!
!
ip cef
!
!
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
voice-card 0
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
controller T1 0/0/0
 cablelength long 0db
!
controller T1 0/1/0
 cablelength long 0db
!
controller T1 0/1/1
 cablelength long 0db
!
controller T1 0/2/0
 cablelength long 0db
!
controller T1 0/2/1
 cablelength long 0db
!
controller T1 0/3/0
 cablelength long 0db
!
controller T1 0/3/1
 cablelength long 0db
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex full
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 speed 115200
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 password password
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  Just needed to create channel-groups on my controllers:

```
controller T1 0/0/0
 cablelength long 0db
 channel-group 0 timeslots 1-24
```

Now I've got serial interfaces!